# Checking if object exists on controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I'm trying to handle the edge case where a user hits my page without the Id being set for whatever reason.  However, I'm having problems detecting when no object is loaded.  I tried this:

```
private final MyObject__c myObj;
public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
  this.myObj = (MyObject__c) stdController.getRecord();
   if(myObj == null){
      system.debug('this happened');
      ...
   }
   system.debug(myObj);
}
```

And debug looks as follows:

> |DEBUG|myObject__c:{}

I also tried:

```
 if(myObj == null || myObj == new MyObject() ){
```

**AND**

```
if(stdController.getId() == null){
```

Both throw a **"Attempt to De-reference null object"** error

Comment: Have you tried the more direct `stdController.getId() == null`?

Comment: @KeithC yes, it also throws a null exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below controller and page do not generate any exceptions, and correctly display "true" when no ID is specified and "false" when an ID is appended to the page URL using `?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

Controller:

```
public class MyController {
    public Boolean b {get; set;}
    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        b = sc.getId() == null;
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="MyController">
    <apex:outputText value="{!b}"/>
</apex:page>
```

`StandardController.getRecord()` returns a valid SObject when no ID is specified as a parameter to allow the "new" case to work, though that SObject does not have an ID value until it is inserted.

Comment: Ahhh, it was actually an issue with a method being called by my VF page.  Correct answer though